# What does Induction on Formula look like?

Tags: logic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV7sJ.png

I know that substitution is left associative so you would substitute every p in C with q and then, as there are no p but q so you replace every q in C with A. But how would prove by induction on complexity of C and induction on formula? Don't you need to know what C is for this exercise?

There was an example before:

$C[p:=A] = C[p:=q][q:=A]$ (theorem: $ \vdash A ≡ A$)

I do not see the connection or How to apply this to prove by induction on formula. Please help.

Comment: I want to first understand what induction on formula or in other words, proof by induction on the set of formula, looks like. (structurally what to base, hypothesis and point/goal to prove)

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

Induction on complexity of formula $C$ means use induction on the number of connectives occurring in the formula.

*(i) Base case* : $n=0$ i.e. $C$ is a formula made of a single "atom" $p$.

Thus, if $C$ is $p$, we have that $C[p := A]$ will be $A$. But also $C[p:=q][q:=A]$ will be $A$, and thus the result holds.

*(ii)* *Induction step* : assume that the property holds for formulas with $n$ occurrences of connectives, and prove it for $n+1$.

Two subcases : one for $\lnot$ and one for a binary connective : $\lor, \land$ etc.

We consider the $\lnot$ subcase.

$C$ is $\lnot B$; thus $C[p:=A]= (\lnot B)[p:=A]= \lnot (B[p:=A])=\lnot (B[p:=q][q:=A])$, applying the induction hypotheses to $B$.

Thus : $C[p:=A]= \lnot (B[p:=q][q:=A])=(\lnot B[p:=q][q:=A])=C[p:=q][q:=A]$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Even the slightest help, hint, guide is helpful!. So I know induction there is base case, induction hypothesis and induction step. So what I am confused is induction on formula meaning. And because of this I don't know how to come up with the base case on formula. Do we always (for these types of questions) write base case with atomic variable p?

Comment: @TaeCoda - in genral induction works for "structure" that looks like natural numbers. Induction for nat works with : Base case :$n=0$; Induction step : assuming that the property holds for $n$, prove it for $n+1$. In the case of induction on complexity of formulas, you have to use induction on the **number** $n$ of connectives. Base case : $n=0$: what is a formula with $0$ connectives ? An *atom*.